# Php Mysql query special characters in Row

Tags: php, mysql

In my Db i have like this words:

```
mysql> select * from link;
 +------------------------+-------+
 | album                  |  id   |
 +------------------------+-------+
 | Kakki_Sattai           |   1   |
 | pk (2014)              |   2   | 
 | Kakki Sattai           |   3   |
 | pk                     |   4   |
 +------------------------+-------+

$query = $_GET['query']; 
$query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM link WHERE (`album` LIKE '%".$query."%')");
```

IF i use:

```
 If query = pk     // Result: pk, pk (2014)                --- Workig Fine
 If query = Kakki  // Result: Kakki Sattai , Kakki_Sattai  --- Workig Fine
```

But if i use:

```
 If query = pk 2014         // Result: No Result     ---( i want both result)
 If query = Kakki Sattai    // Result: Kakki Sattai  ---( Another result Not show)
```

How can i skip special Characters which have in  mysql table?

Comment: `LIKE` statements doesn't split words and search each of them. You might want to do it by hand. You can't find `pk (2014)` by querying `pk 2014`.

Comment: Ok .. So how i can find both?

Comment: Something like @Hephaestus says. Or you might using splitting and seperating like clauses.

Comment: Why are you HTML-escaping data for SQL? Your DB data should not be HTML-escaped, do it when displaying it! Also, why are you using the obsolete `mysql` extension in new code? Use PDO or at least mysqli! And don't interpolate values in your query. Use parametrized queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the spaces in `$query` with `%` so they'll match anything:

```
$query = str_replace(' ', '%', $query);
```

However, if the query is `Sattai Kakki` it still won't match anything, because the order is different from the values in the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind doing some preprocessing on the query strings, you could replace runs of whitespace in them with '%' characters.

So, for example, transform "pk 2014" to "pk%2014", and "Kakki Sattai" to "Kakki%Sattai".

Edit: @Taha Paksu makes a good point. Merely interpolating the '%' into "pk 2014" won't get you *both* rows containing "pk". For that, you'd also have to split the query strings on whitespace, and OR additional LIKE clauses into your query, testing for one or more of the discrete words found between whitespace in the query string.

However, you may want to spend some time analyzing just how permissive or restrictive you want your matching to be before implementing a solution. For example, if you OR additional LIKE tests for each discrete word in the query string (e.g., add the clauses 'OR album LIKE "%pk%" OR album LIKE "%2014%"' to the initial query), you'd get all *other* records with "2014" in the album name, which you probably don't want.

Comment: Didn't knew that wildcards can be used for these kind of conditions too...! Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use query splitting like this:

```
$query = $_GET['query']; 
$query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
$query = implode('\' or `album` LIKE \'',explode(' ',$query));
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM link WHERE (`album` LIKE '%".$query."%')");
```